# how to upload the plugin in wordpress google app engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I managed to install wordpress on google app engine. now when i login to admin and try to install the plugins required, it ask for ftp access.

Please help me to install the plugins in google app engine

Answer (score 2):

`App Engine` is Fully managed, so the configuration is also limited. You can’t edit the `App Engine` filesystem as directories for wordpress are read only by default. Hence, you will not have much control on folder permissions. In order to install plugins you have to install and update plugins on your local instance as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible#updating_wordpress_plugins_and_themes).

What I can suggest is to host your wordpress site to `Compute Engine` or Deploy it to Wordpress to Marketplace.

Also check this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard)